# Geo Location Technologies - Accuracy for Mobile

Tags: android, ios, mobile

Looking for estimates on how accurate each of the technologies for Geo Location on mobile OS such as iOS and Android are:

GPS
IP address
RFID
WiFi
Bluetooth MAC addresses
GSM/CDMA cell IDs

Tried to google this information but just keep getting services like Max Mind

Cheers

Ian

Answer (score 0):

If have access to ACM DL, search "localization" & "smartphone", take a look at most recent ones published on Mobicom, Mobisys or Sigcomm, and you get petty much what you need.

Here's my own estimate which may not be all true:

GPS: 5m, only outdoor;
IP address: >500m;
RFID: unknown;
WiFi: <1m as claimed, but >10m actually, only when multiple APs exits;
Bluetooth: Unknown;
MAC addresses: unknown;
GSM/CDMA cell IDs: >50m